# Generic class with restricted Type parameter

Tags: c#, generics, types

I want to create a generic class that takes a type parameter and restrict that parameter to numeric types or more generally to any type upon which the increment operator ++ can be applied.

I know I can do the following to restrict to structs but obviously there are structs that aren't numeric types and for which the ++ operator is not supported.  Can I do this in C#

```
class Example<T> where T : struct
{
  //Implementation detail
}
```

Comment: This is a frequently requested feature. Implementing it would require changes to both the language and the runtime. It's a _possibility_ for hypothetical future versions, but unlikely to be our highest priority.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generic constraint to match numeric types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329576/generic-constraint-to-match-numeric-types)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx).) You can only constrain the type to:

- Implement a specific interface or derive from a specific class
- Be a `class` or `struct`
- Have a parameterless constructor

Constraining types to have specific operators is a much-requested feature but I believe it will not be in C# 4 either.