# Generic constraint to match numeric types

Tags: c#, generics, numeric

I'm trying to write an extension method on numeric types to be used in a fluent testing framework I'm building. Basically, I want to do this:

```
public static ShouldBeGreaterThan<T>(this T actual, T expected, string message)
    where T : int || T: double || etc...
```

Just `where T : struct` doesn't do, since that will also match `string` and `bool`, and possibly something else I'm forgetting. is there something I can do to match only numeric types? (Specifically types that implement the `>` and `<` operators, so I can compare them... If this means I'm matching dates as well, it doesn't really matter - the extension will still do what I expect.)

Comment: Jon Skeet and Mark Gravell put together some interesting classes for this: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/genericoperators.html

Comment: @Dan actually it is "Marc", but I'll let you off - very few people get it right ;p

Comment: that link is dead. use this instead https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/miscutil/ 
https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/genericoperators.html

Answer (score 69, accepted):

In this case you want to constrain your generic to the [`IComparable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable?view=net-8.0) interface, which gives you access to the `CompareTo` method, since this interface allows you to answer the question `ShouldBeGreaterThan`.

Numeric types will implement that interface and the fact that it also works on strings shouldn't bother you that much.

**Edit:**

*My comment from 2020 is not true anymore!*

Since .NET 7 you could also consider constraining to the [`INumber<TSelf>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.inumber-1?view=net-8.0&viewFallbackFrom=net-5.0) - incidentally, the interface inherits from `IComparable` but would then indeed exclude e.g. the `string` type. Additionally, though, the interface also inherits from the [`IComparisonOperators`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.icomparisonoperators-3?view=net-8.0) interface, which will give you all the operators you'd expect (`<, <=, >=, >, ==, !=`)

Comment: This is a better solution than a more general operator interface for numeric types, at least for this problem.

Comment: Is there a way I can allow the usage of `==` and `>` etc rather than `.Equals()` and `.CompareTo`?

Comment: Those operators are implemented as static methods - that is, currently C# has no way to constrain on static features of a type,

Comment: Note that `IComparable` only seems to work when comparing objects of the same type. It does not seem to work to call `123.CompareTo(123L)`, for example, which can be a problem depending on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 61):

```
where T : struct, 
          IComparable, 
          IComparable<T>, 
          IConvertible, 
          IEquatable<T>, 
          IFormattable
```

That's the closest I can get to a numeric constraint. All the numeric types implement these 5 interfaces, but IFormattable is not implemented by bool, and strings are a reference type, so they're not applicable.

There's some other things that implement these - DateTime for example, so it's not really as required, but prevents a lot of instantiations you don't want.

Comment: Even with this, I cannot seem to use common math operations. `Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'float'`

Answer (score 21):

```
public static bool IsGreaterThan<T>(this T actual, T comp) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    return actual.CompareTo(comp) > 0;
}
```

You can add the struct constraint if you want as well.

Answer (score 9):

It is hard to limit to just numerics, since there is nothing common like `INumeric` to use as the filter. Actually, I suspect the easiest approach here is to *not* insist on the constraint, and use `Comparer<T>.Default.Compare` inside the method.

This inbuilt type supports both the generic `IComparable<T>` and the non-generic `IComparable`, and supports ref-types, value-types and lifted usage via `Nullable<T>`.

For full **operator** usage, look at [MiscUtil's `Operator` class](https://github.com/loory/MiscUtil/blob/master/Operator.cs) and `GreaterThan` etc, which may be useful if you **really** want to use the operator (rather than the interface). It also provides access to the other operators like `Add` etc.

Comment: Marc Gravell said "It is **hard** to limit to just numerics" but it is **possible** both in run time and compile time. Please see my answer to "Is there a constraint that restricts my generic method to numeric types?"  
 question.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32664/is-there-a-constraint-that-restricts-my-generic-method-to-numeric-types

Comment: @Erez that'll work, but is death to performance critical code - lots of boxing and type checking. Somewhere in the C#7.2-C#8.0 period we are likely to see additions to generics to do this much more efficiently.

Comment: I can't wait until this will be supported by Microsoft.

Answer (score 5):

Stackoverflow is littered with this kind of question.  [Take a look at this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=numeric+generic+C%23).  C# doesn't support a way to define a generic type constrained by numbers.  Sadly, your best bet is to implement the extension method on all objects and do a switch based on type or to create a set of methods for ints, doubles, floats, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This workaround may help: [Workaround using policies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32664/c-generic-constraint-for-only-integers/4834066#4834066). It provides compile time safety.