# Can I extend a generic class putting a restriction on the types that can be used?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, extension-methods

I want to extend the IEnumerable class but only for types that can be operated (int, decimal, single and double).

Is this doable? I don't see the way to restrict this:

```
public static class IEnumerableExtension
{
    public static decimal FindBestSubsequence<T> (this IEnumerable<T> source, out int startIndex, out int endIndex)
    {

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to look into 'where T : struct'  Just a thought.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generic constraint to match numeric types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329576/generic-constraint-to-match-numeric-types)

Comment: @BrokenGlass: I really need more things other than Comparable, so its not a dup imho.

Comment: There are pretty much the same suggestions in the other answers to that question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [generic constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) but you can't constrain a type parameter to only be valid for a specific set of types. The closest you could come would be something like:

```
public static decimal FindBestSubsequence<T>
    (this IEnumerable<T> source, out int startIndex, out int endIndex)    
     where T : struct, IConvertible, IFormattable, IComparable<T>, IEquatable<T>,
     IComparable
```

... as those are all interfaces which each of those types implements. However, this wouldn't prevent, say, `Int16` from being used as the type argument. Do you *definitely* not want it to be applicable for an `IEnumerable<short>`? What would go wrong if it were used for that?

You *could* have a set of non-generic public overloads, which then called to a constrained generic *private* method:

```
public static decimal FindBestSubsequence(this IEnumerable<decimal> source,
    out int startIndex, out int endIndex)
{
    return FindBestSubsequenceImpl(source, startIndex, endIndex);
}

public static decimal FindBestSubsequence(this IEnumerable<int> source,
    out int startIndex, out int endIndex)
{
    return FindBestSubsequenceImpl(source, startIndex, endIndex);
}

// etc

// Could constrain T more if it was useful in the method, but we know
// T will only be one of the types we want, because only this class can
// call this method
private static decimal FindBestSubsequence<T>
    (IEnumerable<T> source, out int startIndex, out int endIndex)    
     where T : struct
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. The algorithm I'm writing can work on any numeric type and probably a struct that implements all these interfaces is numeric.

Comment: @SoMoS: Not necessarily. `DateTime` would count, for example. Would that be a problem? In fact, if you only constrain `T` to the interfaces you need to implement the method (probably `IComparable<T>`), what problems are you considering?

Comment: Well, it will execute over DateTime but the result won't have any sense. Maybe I can check the type on runtime and throw something.

Comment: @SoMoS: Would it definitely not make sense? It would help if you could describe what you're implementing. Did you see my edited answer for another alternative?

Comment: @JonSkeet: I'm searching thru a sequence of numbers of find the subsequence that gives the maximum value when adding its values (they are + and - numbers). Therefor, executing the method over an unsigned value has no sense.

Comment: @SoMoS: If you need to add values together, you'll need to work out how you're planning on doing that anyway - seeing as there's no generic way of doing that. (You could potentially do it using `dynamic`, potentially, as just one example.)

Comment: @JonSkeet: you're right, everyone implements the method Add but looks like they have no common base :\ ... still thinking. Bytheway I've found that what I need is to implement the maximum subarray problem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem).

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict to value types by using `where T : struct`

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx):

> where T: struct
>
> The type argument must be a value type. Any value type except Nullable
>   can be specified. See Using Nullable Types (C# Programming Guide) for
>   more information.