# Guard against arguments that are out of range

Tags: c#, .net, generics, compare, numeric

I'm looking for a way to guard against arguments that are out of range, something along the lines of...

```
public static class Guard {

    public static void AgainstOutOfRange<TArgument>(TArgument argument,
        TArgument minInclusive, TArgument maxInclusive)
        where TArgument : struct, IComparable<TArgument>, IConvertible
    {
        if(argument.CompareTo ????
    }
```

Looking for 'numeric constraints' on generics I stumpled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329576/generic-constraint-to-match-numeric-types) where @Lee suggests

```
public static bool IsGreaterThan<T>(this T actual, T comp) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    return actual.CompareTo(comp) > 0;
}
```

I'm however not sure if this is inclusive, exclusive and how to check for 'IsSmallerThan' (*I do not fully understand `IComparable` yet*)

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `IComparable`?  That's a pretty good way to start understanding it, that or just looking for info on Google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- *Inclusive* means that we're going to include the lower and upper bounds as valid values. For example, `Guard.AgainstOutOfRange(5, 0, 5)` should accept `5` as a valid argument, since we're allowing `0` to `5` *inclusive*.
- *Exclusive* means that we're going to exclude the lower and upper bounds. For example, `Guard.ArgumentOutOfRange(5, 0, 5)` should reject `5` as a valid argument, since we're not allowing the upper and lower bounds themselves as valid values.

With that in mind, I think you're just looking for:

```
if(argument.CompareTo(minInclusive) < 0 ||
    argument.CompareTo(maxInclusive) > 0)
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Argument out of range");
}
```

Here we're saying:

- If the result of comparing `argument` to `minInclusive` is *less than zero* (`argument` is less than `minInclusive`) OR
- The result of comparing `argument` to `maxInclusive` is *greater than zero* (`argument` is greater than `maxInclusive`)

... Then we have an invalid argument. Note that if the comparison is *equal* to zero in either case, we treat that as an *valid* argument (zero is not greater than or less than zero, so it passes our test).

If we were to make our test *exclusive*, we could include the result of `CompareTo` equaling zero in our check:

```
if(argument.CompareTo(minInclusive) <= 0 ||
    argument.CompareTo(maxInclusive) >= 0)
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Argument out of range");
}
```

Then we'd be saying *if the parameter is equal to the lower or upper bound, that's an invalid argument too.*

[The documentation for `IComparable.CompareTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto(v=vs.110).aspx) explains the result of `instance.CompareTo(obj)`:

> **Less than zero** This instance precedes obj in the sort order.
>
> **Zero**: This instance occurs in the same position in the sort order as obj.
>
> **Greater than zero**: This instance follows obj in the sort order.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for the detailed explanation. Especially the last part clears it up pretty much. And your latest edit will definitely be helpful for others.