# Converto a String Into a T type C#

Tags: c#, string, templates, type-conversion

I would like to create a function that has as input a string and return the converted string according to the T type.

I tried with

```
static T convertStringTemplate<T>(string myString)
        {
            return T.Parse(myString);
        }
```

However it does not work. Do you have any idea?

Comment: `T` is any type?

Comment: T can be any numeric type ( int, float, double,...)

Answer (score 1):

Generics don't work like that. Generics have to be instantiable for any `T` that matches the constraints (no limits in your case). `convertStringTemplate<object>` is a simple example that would pretty obviously not work.

You write in a comment:

> T can be any numeric type ( int, float, double,...)

If it only has to work for numeric types, then it's much simpler. Just call [`Convert.ChangeType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I tried with  
`return Convert.ChangeType(myString, typeof(T));` however typeof does not recognize T

Comment: @GVa Either you're misreading the error message (`Convert.ChangeType` returns `object`, which you can then cast to `T`, but if this is the problem, it's not about `typeof`), or you've not put it in a generic method with a generic type parameter named `T`.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to use the `IConvertible` interface:

```
static T ConvertStringTemplate<T>(string myString, IFormatProvider formatProvider = null)
{
    formatProvider = formatProvider ?? System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    return (T)((IConvertible)myString).ToType(typeof(T), formatProvider);
}
```

If you want to restrict `T` to a numeric type, the closest constraint you may use is the following one (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3329735/3670737) ):

```
static T ConvertStringTemplate<T>(string myString, IFormatProvider formatProvider = null)
    where T :
        struct, 
        IComparable, 
        IComparable<T>, 
        IConvertible, 
        IEquatable<T>, 
        IFormattable
{
    formatProvider = formatProvider ?? System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    return (T)((IConvertible)myString).ToType(typeof(T), formatProvider);
}
```

Usage:

```
var x = ConvertStringTemplate<int>("12"); // results in 12
```

[Edit]
As stated in comments, you probably wanted to use the current culture while converting the string, so I added an `IFormatProvider` custom parameter to the method.

Comment: Heh, the `IConvertible` interface is exactly what `Convert.ChangeType` (which I suggested in my answer) would end up using anyway. You may want to avoid `InvariantCulture`. The OP attempted to call `T.Parse`, which if it worked would perform a culture-sensitive parse.

Comment: @hvd Didn't know `Convert.ChangeType` used the `IConvertible` interface internally. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: This will blow up at runtime.

Comment: @KennethK. What should blow up? [DotNetFiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ugMd26)

Answer (score -1):

Creating an instance of a type whose name is specified, using the named assembly and default constructor, can be done with  [Activator.CreateInstance Method (String, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4(v=vs.110).aspx)